# double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c, free, singly-linked-list

The question asks to delete the even data nodes from a singly linked list.
This is my code snippet:

```
void deleteEven (node **head){
    node *prev, *curr,*del;
    curr=*head;
    prev=NULL;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        if((curr->data)%2==0){
            if(prev==NULL)
            {
                del=curr;
                *head=curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                del=curr;
                prev->next=curr->next;
            }
            free(del);
        }
        else
        {
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)

Kindly explain the cause of the error, and how can I rectify it.

Comment: You call `free` multiple times on the same node. To rectify it, debug your code and check your calls to free (and probably your pointer updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove a node, your loop continues but you haven't updated `curr` to point to the next node.

That means the very next iteration you will dereference the now deleted node and have *undefined behavior*.

If you remove a node you need to update `curr` (but not `prev`):

```
if((curr->data)%2==0){
    if(prev==NULL)
    {
        del=curr;
        *head=curr->next;
    }
    else
    {
        del=curr;
        prev->next=curr->next;
    }

    // Update current node here
    curr=curr->next;

    free(del);
}
```